# Nested outcome categories in a multinomial logistic

Tags: logistic, modeling, multinomial-distribution

I’m modeling a target-shooting video game. A player can shoot and hit the target, shoot and miss, or switch weapons. For simplicity, the outcomes are `HIT`, `MISS`, `NEW_WEAPON`. I have covariates on player and weapon properties. The data are unbalanced: some players play a lot, some a little, some on one visit, some on multiple, and the targets are randomly generated with varying difficulty.

**Some weapons are better for some targets, but switching has a penalty in the game, so players don’t like to switch. What I want to ask is whether switching is a good strategy on average, and whether it’s more effective for some players than others.**

I’m thinking I’ll use a two-level logistic regression, but not a baseline-categories multinomial model.

1. A logistic regression of the outcomes `HIT`+`MISS` as 0 vs. `NEW_WEAPON` as 1. Including an intercept for each player will tell me a player’s tendency to fire weapons vs. switch weapons.
2. Then I can include this intercept as a covariate in a second logistic regression, this time of the outcomes `MISS` as 0 vs. `HIT` as 1. This covariate would have slope $\beta$, which tells me the effect of the tendency to fire a weapon vs. switch weapons on average.
3. As an extension to (2), I can build a logistic regression of `MISS` as 0 vs. `HIT` as 1 with slopes $\beta_p$ per player, which tells me whether switching is more effective for some players than others.

**Does this sound reasonable? Any suggestions? I'm concerned that reusing the observations of `HIT` and `MISS` in (1) and in (2) is somehow not right.**